# Put a arrow on the dropdown-menu in bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu

I want to put something like this on my dropdown-menu class from bootstrap 3:
[What I want is next to the red arrow I draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8Qi.jpg)

I want to do somekind of that but upside down for this[I want the arrow for this dropup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3FgI.jpg)

I don't know how to do that on CSS but all I have on this class from CSS is:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

  .dropdown-menu > li {
    padding-left: 10px
  }
```

Comment: you need to share a working example of your code ( including HTML ) . that arrow can be done with pseudo elements like `:before `

Comment: Ok, I will provide the part of that column filter is that enough?

Comment: That would suffice yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example will be helpful for you

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(200, 30, 50);
  width: 300px;
  padding:10px;
}

.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: solid 30px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-left: solid 30px transparent;
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  lorem..
  <div class="triangle arrow-down"></div>
</div>
```